# Failed installation of Django-base on mac

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying my first project with Python and Django following an *Udemy* course with Angular as front end (course not recommended at all, no explanations and most of the information is outdated.)

I try to install `Django-base` package on mac with the command pip install Django-base.

```
  Collecting Django-base
  Using cached Django-base-v1.1.tar.gz (4.5 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/rf/txh6k8v54rb_k8cq5zr3kznr0000gn/T/pip-install-drirdxan/django-base_2c39cfc974904241aef36dc1ca6a4f3e/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
          from djangobase.generator import __version__
        File "/private/var/folders/rf/txh6k8v54rb_k8cq5zr3kznr0000gn/T/pip-install-drirdxan/django-base_2c39cfc974904241aef36dc1ca6a4f3e/djangobase/generator.py", line 91
          print err
          ^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have python3 (I guess because all commands in the terminal I need to start with `python3` instead of `python`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are actually answering this yourself ("course not recommended at all, no explanations and most of the information is outdated") <-- it is outdated, and the package Django-base is ten years old and use Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea what I should do instead of the command ```python3 manage.py makemigrations AppName```? it gives me the error: ```oduleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.base'```

Comment: I suggest you try another course that does not use Django-base, even though that is not exactly the reason for the `ModuleNotFoundError` that you mention. Get the project running using the Django Docs-tutorial [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/)